# WordPress change upload_dir for specific files to root dont work

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to place PDF files uploaded via the media library in a separate folder in the root directory. I have already developed a filter for this and the files are stored correctly. However, the permalink of the file is wrong and contains the URL as well as the path.

**I use the following source code (excerpt)**

```
$customdir = 'custom-uploads';
$path['path']    = wp_normalize_path( ABSPATH . $customdir );
$path['url']     = home_url( '/' . $customdir );
$path['subdir']  = "/" . $customdir;
$path['basedir'] = $path['path'];
$path['baseurl'] = $path['url'];
```

**The object (path) before the filter looks like this:**

```
[22-Apr-2022 13:59:12 UTC] Array
(
    [path] => /var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/wp-content/uploads/2022/04
    [url] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04
    [subdir] => /2022/04
    [basedir] => /var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/wp-content/uploads
    [baseurl] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads
    [error] => 
)
```

**Before the return:**

```
[22-Apr-2022 13:59:12 UTC] Array
(
    [path] => /var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/custom-uploads
    [url] => https://example.com/custom-uploads
    [subdir] => /custom-uploads
    [basedir] => /var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/custom-uploads
    [baseurl] => https://example.com/custom-uploads
    [error] => 
)
```

**But the permalink of the file is now as follows:**

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads//var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/custom-uploads/file.pdf
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the permalink assembled, and how is that done? Is it your code? Are there other filters after yours, which could additionally modify the array values? The permalink starts with `https://example.com/wp-content/` but this base url is not in the "Before return" array - how comes?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Hi Lars and thanks for your reply. The source is currently running on a clean and up-to-date WP instance without any other plugins, so I can rule out that other filters are affecting the permalink. I modify the permalink exclusively via the posted code above. So the permalink is composed by WordPress via my modified path variable.

Comment: Then I guess try changing "path"

Comment: `ABSPATH` is probably a _local_ path, and the same as "basedir". Try removing ABSPATH...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Thats not working. If I remove the ABSPATH, the permalink looks like before (non-edited) and the file will be saved in the wp-admin/custom-uploads folder.

Comment: Could you please show some code your filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a filter for the [`wp_get_attachment_url` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) to right the URL composed by Wordpress.

```php
/**
 * Filters the attachment URL.
 *
 * @param string $url           URL for the given attachment.
 * @param int    $attachment_id Attachment post ID.
 */
function right_composed_attachment_url( $url, $attachment_id ) {
    $wrong_base_url = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads//var/www/srv/apps/apptest01/custom-uploads';
    $uploads = wp_get_upload_dir();
    $correct_base_url = $uploads['baseurl'];
    $custom_upload_has_wrong_base_url = strpos( $c, $wrong_base_url ) !== false;
    
    if ( $custom_upload_has_wrong_base_url ) {
      return str_replace( $wrong_base_url, $correct_base_url, $url );
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_url', 'right_composed_attachment_url' );
```